# Components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document - LexisNexis service

Tags: guidewire

> **ERROR **: [XSD] src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'ns0:SOAPFaultInfo'. It was detected that 'ns0:SOAPFaultInfo' is in
> namespace 'urn:lnrisk:ws:wsinsmultiproduct:wsinsmultiproduct', but
> components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema
> document '{Schema document name}'. If this is the incorrect namespace,
> perhaps the prefix of 'ns0:SOAPFaultInfo' needs to be changed. If this
> is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be
> added to '{webservice URL}'.

We are consuming this web service and the vendor says it's because of the higher JDK version of the consuming system. They have recently made changes to the WSDL.

Has anyone faced this issue earlier?

We suppressed the error by making changes to the gradle file but that did not work.

The vendor says no another user is facing the issue.

Comment: Are you trying to say that the namespace prefix is incorrect? If the request works from a SOAP utility or tool like Postman, I would consider comparing the exact request payloads with namespaces and their prefix. I encountered a similar issue where a vendor was using .NET and their SOAP service didn't like Guidewire's SOAP envelope prefixes even though the request structure was legit. What version of Java and Guidewire are you on and what version is the vendor using? I believe SOAP 1.1 and 1.2 should work irrespective of java.

Comment: We Upgraded our GW system from v9 to v10 . The jdk version now is Amazon Corretto 11.0.2 . When I put the same wsdl in my v9 system which uses jdk 8  it does not throw an error . We are not given the vendor jdk details. Is there a way I can fix this issue at our end rather than the vendor end

Comment: Can you print the entire Soap envelope along with the request in both v8 and v9 and then check if anything changed in v9?